# Lsyncd 2.2.2 ownership and permission issue

Tags: centos, rsync, nginx, centos-7

I'm having an issue where files are been copied to the remote server except the owner/group of replicated files on the target server is always '1002'. The permissions of the source are respected and replicated correctly on the target. I just can't figure out a way to preserve the owner (and group) of the replicated files.

Lsyncd Version: 2.2.2

my setting below:

```
settings {
    logfile = "/var/log/lsyncd/lsyncd.log",
    statusFile = "/var/log/lsyncd/lsyncd.status"
}

sync {
    default.rsyncssh,
    source="/home",
    host="1*52.*.15",
    targetdir="/home/",
    delete = "running", -- prevents deletion of files on startup (ie when a server comes back online, don't delete files that are new on the backup)
    delay = 5, -- run every 5 seconds instead of default 20
    exclude = {
        "/home/backup",
    },
    rsync = {
        archive = true, -- use the archive flag in rsync
        perms = true, -- Keep the permissions
        owner = true, -- Keep the owner
        compress = true,
        acls = true,
            xattrs = true,
        _extra = {"-a"}, -- Sometimes permissions and owners isn't copied correctly so the _extra can be used for any flag in rsync
    }
}
```

lsyncd log error:

```
Dec 15 21:42:47 server1.*.group lsyncd[21033]: sending incremental file list
Dec 15 21:42:47 server1.*.group lsyncd[21033]: rsync: failed to set times on "/home/admin/conf": Operation not permitted (1)
Dec 15 21:42:47 server1.*.group lsyncd[21033]: admin/conf/
Dec 15 21:42:47 server1.*.group lsyncd[21033]: sent 5,387 bytes  received 160 bytes  3,698.00 bytes/sec
Dec 15 21:42:47 server1.*.group lsyncd[21033]: total size is 2,849,404,839  speedup is 513,683.94
Dec 15 21:42:47 server1.*.group lsyncd[21033]: rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1178) [sender=3.1.2]
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is the uid/gid of the files on the local system do not correspond to the uid/gid on your target system.

Check the user/group ids on the local system and create the same user/group on target system.

```
# On source system
$ ls -l /home/admin/conf
-rw-r--r--. 1 user1 user1 1.0K Jul 13  2018 /home/admin/conf

$ id user1
uid=1002(user1) gid=1002(user1) groups=1002(user1)

# On target system
$ useradd -u 1002 -g 1002 user1
```

Answer (score 0):

When RSYNC transmits a file with preserve ownership,  it transmits, not the username / Group name, but the UID and GID of the owner.

So, your experience with the 1002 means that that UID is not in use on the target system.

You can resolve this in one of 2 ways:

- Delete the old user, and recreate it using the UID setting in useradd.
  -- This is probably the cleanest way you can do this as you won't have to chown or chmod anything.
- Update the UID and GID using usermod.
  -- If you do this, you will need to chown the files in your home directory, and could experience other unexpected side effects for other files owned by that user.

List item